# How to completely refresh a page right when navigating to it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to refresh a page (same effect as click Command+R on Mac OS) when navigating to that page.

For example:

I have "abc.com/login" for the Login page which will navigate to "abc.com/dashboard" for Dashboard after login successfully. At the moment, it navigates to the Dashboard without completely refresh the whole page.

I would like it to completely refresh everything. By "refresh", I mean it is the same as clicking Command+R on the browser.

Comment: Why do you need to completely refresh the page? Browsers cache files for a good reason. Forcing your site to bypass the browser cache every time you load the dashboard page is not best practice.

Answer (score 1):

`this.$router.go()` without parameter will reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vue built-in `forceUpdate` function, like this:

`vm.$forceUpdate()`

or if it's inside the component, you can use

`this.$forceUpdate();`

References:

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate
- https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

Comment: This forces the component to re-render. It does not cause the browser to reload the files from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
window.location.reload(true);
```

Passing `true` to the reload function will force the page to reload from the server. Alternatively, pass `false` to reload from cache.
This is vanilla javascript so it is not a vueJS only solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
window.location.href = "/dashboard?key=" + Math.random()
```

Instead of Math.random() something else can be used if required